# Creating a css3 blur on hover transition

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I would like the effect on the artist boxes here but I am not sure how to recreate this, please could someone point me in the right direction.

https://www.coachella.com/art-at-coachella/

I have looked at the source code but I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Before or after hover?

Comment: I want to create the on hover effect with the blur box expanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are using `filter` css property to add blur on hover.

HTML:

```
<div class="image">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image:hover img {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
}
```

[Dome fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/devxlt/4hffu8m5/)

Or You could use SVG blug filter (better cross browser support)

```
<svg viewbox="0 0 200 200">
  <filter id="svgBlur" x="-5%" y="-5%" width="110%" height="110%" >
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="5" />
  </filter>
  <image xlink:href="https://placekitten.com/200/200" width="200px" height="200px" />
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
svg {
  width: 200px;
}

svg:hover {
  filter: url(#svgBlur);
}
```

[Dome fiddle with svg and css filters](https://jsfiddle.net/devxlt/4hffu8m5/1/)

Comment: that is great thank you but is there anyway to make the blur expand from the middle like the example?